# Web-to-lead reassign lead owner trigger

Tags: leads, web2lead

I have a web-to-lead form setup, and it works fine. The default assignment is just set to my user, but I want to run a trigger to set the owner based on some criteria in custom fields I've created on the `User` records. *There are no other active `assignment rules`*

The trigger runs when I hit the web-to-lead form, and doesn't have any errors, but when I check the newly created Lead record, the owner is still assigned to my user (the default for web-to-lead)?

I've tried changing the trigger from a `before insert` to an `after insert` both with the same result?

Before insert:

```
trigger SDRLeadQueue on Lead (before insert) {
    system.debug('**** LEAD TRIGGER AFTER INSERT/UPDATE ****');
    for(Lead lead : Trigger.new){
        ...
        User sdrUser = sdrLeadQueueUsers.remove(0);
        lead.OwnerId = sdrUser.id;
    }
}
```

After insert (same logic, just need to select the lead/update it):

```
trigger SDRLeadQueue on Lead (after insert) {
    system.debug('**** LEAD TRIGGER AFTER INSERT/UPDATE ****');
    for(Lead lead : Trigger.new){
        Lead newLead = [SELECT Id,OwnerId FROM Lead 
                        WHERE id =: lead.id LIMIT 1];
        ...
        User sdrUser = sdrLeadQueueUsers.remove(0);
        newLead.OwnerId = sdrUser.id;
        ...
        update newLead;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my hunch:

If we go thru the [order of execution](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm) of triggers it mentions running the assignment rules after both the `after` and `before` triggers have finished running, which implies owner field will be changed again when the assignment rules fire. And here's another [link](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=faq_leads_who_owns_new.htm) which explains how the leads are assigned when it is generated from web-to-lead. It says that if the assignment rule fail to locate an owner (in your case there are no assignment rule) then the lead will be assigned to the default owner as mentioned in the setting or  If you do not use assignment rules, all web leads will be assigned to the Default Lead Creator.

Setting the owner in a future method should do the trick as that will be considered another transaction.

Comment: Using an `@Future` method seems so unnecessary when the operation is so straight forward!! I'm going to try re-enabling a basic `lead-assignment` role (the one that comes pre-installed). The `chatter tracking` shows the value being assigned from _blank_ to the default assignment user from web-to-lead which implies the owner isn't even getting assigned by my trigger!?

Comment: Used an `@Future` method and the assignment worked like a charm. _I understand the order-of-ops logic_ but the `after insert` trigger, or workflow rules I had _should have set the owner_ regardless before the web-to-lead default was assigned!? I even watched the workflow rule (assignment rule, but debug log shows as workflow rule) execute in the debug log! Sigh...